How to use jito bundle to buy and sell tokens?
I want to write a script to accomplish this functions, instead of using jupiter . any one can teach me how to do it ?

Here is a great video about Jito Bundles
Jito Bundles by Quicknode
If you have any questions more specific, please ask away

You can use jito-ts node module.
